# Concatenate values of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, join

I have the following data frame:

```
    Zone    Store   Department  TTLSales    
0   APV                         220 
1   APV     ST12                100 
2   APV     ST12    Elec        40  
3   APV     ST12    Grocery     20  
4   APV     ST12    CPG         40
```

I wish to include one column concatenating the values as:

```
    Zone    Store   Department  TTLSales    id
0   APV                         220         APV
1   APV     ST12                100         APV.ST12
2   APV     ST12    Elec        40          APV.ST12.Elec
3   APV     ST12    Grocery     20          APV.ST12.Grocery
4   APV     ST12    CPG         40          APV.ST12.CPG
```

I am new to pandas and have spent lot of time but could not wrap my head around.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
#Firstly fill NaN's of the columns:
df[['Zone','Store','Department']]=df[['Zone','Store','Department']].fillna('')
#Finally:
df['id']=(df['Zone']+'.'+df['Store']+'.'+df['Department']).str.rstrip('.')
```

**OR**

If there are more then 4 columns then use `apply()`(performance wise the 1st method is fast as compared to apply):

```
#Firstly fill NaN's of the columns:
df[['Zone','Store','Department']]=df[['Zone','Store','Department']].fillna('')
#Finally:
df['id'] = df[['Zone','Store','Department']].apply('.'.join, axis=1).str.rstrip('.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.agg` with `str.join` here.

```
df = df.fillna('')
df['id'] = df[['Zone','Store','Department']].agg('.'.join, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably overworked , but here is another way of solving this using `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

cols = ['Zone','Store','Department']
f = lambda x,y : (x +'.'+y).str.rstrip(".")
#or# f = lambda x,y : x.str.cat(y,sep='.').str.rstrip(".")

df['id'] = reduce(f,map(df.fillna('').get, cols))
```

---

```
print(df)

  Zone Store Department  TTLSales                id
0  APV   NaN        NaN       220               APV
1  APV  ST12        NaN       100          APV.ST12
2  APV  ST12       Elec        40     APV.ST12.Elec
3  APV  ST12    Grocery        20  APV.ST12.Grocery
4  APV  ST12        CPG        40      APV.ST12.CPG
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's like a generalized example.
First create a small simple dataframe.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Zone':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'Store':['', 'st2', 'st3']})
```

Then create new column with name 'id'.

```
    df['id'] = (df.Zone + '.' + df.Store).str.strip('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
df["id"]=df["Zone"]+"."+df["Store"]+"."+df["Department"]
df["id"]=df["id"].apply(lambda x:x.rstrip("."))
df
```

result

```
    Zone    Store   Department  TTLSales    id
0   APV                          220       APV
1   APV     ST12                 100       APV.ST12
2   APV     ST12    Elec         40        APV.ST12.Elec
3   APV     ST12    Grocery      20        APV.ST12.Grocery
4   APV     ST12    CPG          10        APV.ST12.CPG
```